# How To show Data in Table with the help of SegmentViewControl in Xcode

Tags: ios

hi Friends can any one tell help me show Data in row in Table with the click on SegmentViewControl in Xcode

Comment: This has. Othing to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UISegmentedControl` is just a combination of multiple buttons. Here is what you have to do (considering you want to load some data in a table when a specific index on the control is selected)

- Create a  `UISegmentedControl` in your class (programmatically or using xib).
- Link it with a `selector` in the class (a function).
- Reload your table in the function (`tableView reloadData`)
- If you want different data for different segments, check the `selectedSegmentIndex` value and load different data in your `cellForRowAtIndexpath`.
  For further reading
- [Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html)
- [UISegmentedControl Tutorial](https://mobileappmastery.com/here-is-how-you-use-uisegmentedcontrol/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thnx Buddy for Answer :)

Answer (score 0):

When you click on SegmentViewControl then reload the table: `[tabelView reloadData];`